# Spark : How to filter columns and perform operations and eventually write all columns to a file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a file into a dataframe with a lot of columns and rows but I’m interested in a single column to perform my actions (repartition, filter etc) so I plan on filtering the columns I do not need but when I write the final data frame to another output file, how can I include all the columns that were filtered out?

I’m reading all the input paths like:

```
val inputDF = spark.read.parquet(path).selectExpr(status).repartition(repartitionCount, col(status))

----
Do other operations on the inputDF
----

inputDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputPath)
```

I’m only interested in the column “status” here (I tried loading all the columns but there are way too many).

Is there a way to save all the other columns before saving to the final output Path?

Answer (score 0):

Let say the original dataframe as `DF` which have many columns and the final result is `finalDF`. You want to select the status column but there should be an identifier such as id (if you have). Then there should be two dataframe which have all the columns except 'status'(`restDF`) and only have 'status' and 'id' columns (`inputDF`)

```
val DF = spark.read.parquet(path)
val restDF = DF.drop("status")
val inputDF = DF.select($"id", $"status").repartition(repartitionCount, $"status")
```

By using `inputDF` do your things and finally, you can join those two dataframe.

```
val finalDF = restDF.join(inputDF, restDF("id") === inputDF("id"))
```

If you are not using any id, then the data will be mixed, which means that the first row can go to the 5th row and so on.